# Separate Logins in asp.met MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Still learning, so excuse the generalisation's.
Basically, I have a login for regular users.
I want a separate login for an administrator so he/she can alter content on a view in the application.

The problem being that all the user tables are sync'd with another product, so I can't just add a random user, as it will effect both this application and another.
Idealy, when the application runs and the login screen is displayed for regular users the admin user will type "/Admin" after the application's name in the url and this would re-direct to a separate Admin login view/screen.

So is there a clean way to add this user and create a second log in ?

I'm not looking for someone to do all the work for me, I just need an idea as to how to proceed.

Comment: Why not create a flag to distinguish the common user of adoministradores?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use MVC Areas.

Take a look at this link:
http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/

Let me know if you have any other problem.